# Is COALESCE sargable now?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016

One of my developers is arguing that `COALESCE(column, default value) = default value` is now sargable.  Is that right?

I ran the following test, and think it implies that `COALESCE` is non-sargable.

```
USE tempdb;

SELECT @@VERSION;
-- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-CU3-GDR) (KB3194717) - 13.0.2186.6 (X64)   Oct 31 2016 18:27:32   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor) 

CREATE TABLE Test 
(
    ID int primary key clustered, 
    Mod6 int null, 
    INDEX IX_Mod6 NONCLUSTERED (Mod6)
);

INSERT INTO Test (ID, Mod6)
SELECT object_id as ID, case when name like '%k%' then null else object_id % 6 end as Mod6
FROM sys.objects;

SELECT Mod6
FROM Test WITH (INDEX = IX_Mod6, FORCESEEK)
where Mod6 is null or Mod6 = 0;
-- Plan shows expected seek

SELECT Mod6
FROM Test WITH (INDEX = IX_Mod6, FORCESEEK)
WHERE COALESCE(Mod6, 0) = 0;
-- Error:
-- Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
-- Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints 
-- defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints 
-- and without using SET FORCEPLAN.
```

Comment: Did your developer argue with any evidence whatsoever?

Comment: I read this post: http://josef-richberg.squarespace.com/journal/2010/1/28/is-a-case-statement-considered-sargable.html  I do not think that a concrete answer can be derived to answer this post.  (But maybe somebody else knows better.)

Comment: @RLF - that article doesn't say anything that would indicate that it is sargable. This is not a demonstration of it being sargable. http://twitpic.com/107ms0. The non sargability is that it prevents a seek on the columns used in the `CASE` expression - not that the result of the expression can't then be used to seek into something else.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, "The execution plan looked the same no matter how I write it" - He ignored the fact that neither was performing a seek based on the `COALESCE`d column.

Comment: @Mitch Sure, but that's not evidence in any sane interpretation of the word. That is more like explaining [how the bear tax is working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fm2W0sq9ddU).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Haha.  Agreed, but it did raise an interesting question that I didn't know the answer to.

Comment: Oh I don't fault you for asking the question, especially since you attempted to disprove it first. I was just suggesting that maybe your developer should learn to do the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No `COALESCE` is not sargable.

Your own test demonstrates this well.

An exception would be if you created a computed column with the `COALESCE` expression and indexed that.

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
(
    ID int primary key clustered, 
    Mod6 int null, 
    Foo AS COALESCE(Mod6, 0),
    INDEX IX_Mod6 NONCLUSTERED (Mod6),
    INDEX IX2_Mod6 NONCLUSTERED (Foo),
);
```

You could end up with a seek on that

```
SELECT Mod6
FROM Test WITH (INDEX = IX2_Mod6, FORCESEEK)
WHERE COALESCE(Mod6, 0) = 0;
```

`ISNULL` is marginally more sargable in that if it is totally redundant it can be optimised out and not prevent a seek.

i.e. if the column `Mod6` is defined as `NOT NULL` then the following can produce a seek.

```
SELECT Mod6
FROM Test 
WHERE ISNULL(Mod6, 0) = 0;
```

But this of course doesn't supply any benefit over just doing

```
WHERE Mod6 = 0
```